# CI/CD flutter, firebase, android play store does not work

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin, code-signing, github-actions

I am trying to setup CI/CD with github actions / flutter for android. Google sign in works localy but after deploy from github actions it does not. It looks like there is no matching SHA in firebase.
I was debuging github actions build outputing **gradle signingReport** and it looks like there is no **debug.keystore** and for some reason all libraries I use are signed exactly with debug key store and only app it self is signed with release key. Becausue of this reason google signin does not work.

Do you know why other libraries signed with debug key?
Is there a way to sign them with release key?
Or maybe I should pass android debug key store to github actions (I have found 0 mentions about this in many blogposts)

Output from CI/CD:

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: /home/runner/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: /home/runner/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: release
Store: /home/runner/work/_temp/key.jks
Alias: ***
MD5: 10:....:C8
------------->  SHA1: 6F:93:......95:98
SHA-256: 48:.......:6F
Valid until: Sunday, June 21, 2048



---------> Task :google_sign_in:signingReport
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: none
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: /home/runner/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
------------> Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: /home/runner/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: /home/runner/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :image_cropper:signingReport
Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: none
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: /home/runner/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
```

P. S. Build.gradle is configured with release sign

P. P. S. If I upload to play store release build made on pc - everything works

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing SHA which was generated by play store (can be found under "App Integrity") and had to be copied to firebase.

However debug sign issue remains and is tracked here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76484